# How do I start a second console application in Visual Studio when one is already running

Tags: visual-studio-2008, wcf, console-application

I am working through some examples in a WCF book. There is a Host project and Client project within a single solution. Both are console applications. The Host is the startup app, but the Client app doesn't seem to open the Console like the book says. Book says while the Host is running, run the Client. The Run button is disabled tho as it is already running. The book example definitely has them in the same solution and a single instance of Visual Studio. Anyways, what am I missing here? I have done this with two instances of VS, but I truly have never does this in a single instance. Any help is always appreciated.

Cheers,
~ck in San Diego

Comment: Ha ha, I had the same problem.  I know exactly which book you were reading.

Comment: The question helped me as well. Like 'Buh Buh', I know what book you are reading !!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Right-Click on the host project in solution explorer then go to debug -> start new instance.

Once it is running you can do the same thing to start the client project, or, you can press F5 like normal if the client project is the startup project.

Comment: I do not see this option on VS Professional when I right click on a Console app project. Is it available only on higher versions?

Answer (score 24):

You can also make both console apps start at once when you debug.

- In Solution Explorer, right-click the solution, and select **Properties**.
- In the left pane, select **Common Properties** | **Startup Project**.
- Then, on the right, select **Multiple Startup Projects**.
- You can set any number of your projects to start - with or without debugging.