# Start multiple instances of console app in Visual Studio (with different args)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, console-application, visual-studio-debugging, multiple-instances

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565153/how-do-i-start-a-second-console-application-in-visual-studio-when-one-is-already) ...and the answer shows how to start another instance of a console app in Visual Studio when you already have one running.

I want to do the same **BUT** passing different `args[]`.  For example, when debugging I want to start up **2 instances** of `MyConsoleApp.exe` as follows...

```
"MyConsoleApp.exe Agent1"
"MyConsoleApp.exe Agent2"
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

*(Using Visual Studio 2015 Pro)*

Comment: One option is to attach the debugger after starting your app from the command line with the desired args.  This will require you to put in a `Sleep` or some such wait code at the start of your app, in order to give you enough time to attach the debugger.

Comment: A nice way to quickly attach the debugger with a single button press is to put a `Debug.Fail()` somewhere early in the startup code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you can't. What I'd do is open the solution in two VS instances and run it. Or else you can give it a go the following way too ( haven't tried this but ideally it should work)

1. Create two console projects and add all your files as 'linked' files on both projects ( the same .cs files being used on both projects)
2. Go to the solution and set one project as 'Start with Debugging' and other as start without debugging. ( or may be both as Start with Debugging- depending on your scenario) [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165413.aspx) is how you could do this.